# Ignore files in Git that are regenerated with unchanged content

Tags: git

I have files that are generated on a regular basis (CSS files from Less). The content is the same but the file is considered different/changed by Git.

It's probably because the date of creation/modification has changed, but I'm wondering how can I avoid committing these files?

I need them on the repository, but I **don't want to commit** them when the content **hasn't** changed.

**Edit:**

Solution found here: [Git flag non-modified files as modified when generated by LESS or if line separator has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931300/git-flag-non-modified-files-as-modified-when-generated-by-less-or-if-line-separa/26931371)

Comment: Call `git remove <file>` to untrack a file

Comment: I don't want to untrack it. I need it.

Comment: You seem pretty adamant, but you shouldn't need it, and you shouldn't track it. Git isn't for tracking generated content. You should track the source files. Also, Git will  not track changes to timestamps. If it's letting you commit it, it's because the contents have changed. Perhaps there is a time-stamp inside the file, in a comment? Look closer at `git diff` and figure out what is actually changing.

Comment: The file won't be deleted but untracked so that `git commit -a` won't update the file

Comment: In this specific case I need to track the generated file also. The source isn't good enough.

Comment: Okay, I close this one then! Thanks.

Comment: @msrd0 There is no such Git verb as `remove`... You probably meant `rm`.

Comment: @Jubos Oh sorry you're correct

Comment: I have found an acceptable answer and *it is not* on the "duplicated" topic but on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931300/git-flag-non-modified-files-as-modified-when-generated-by-less-or-if-line-separa/26931371 I've asked to reopen but it's not useful actually, I've edited the main post, didn't know I could.

Answer (score 2):

> ... but I don't want to commit them when the content hasn't changed.

You **can't**. Git tracks **content**. Git will not allow you to commit a file that has no changes to its content. The premise of your question is incorrect. The file's content has necessarily changed, or you could not commit anything.

Comment: Then I guess the content hasn't changed, but maybe the way the file is saved as changed! I'm thinking about the CLRF/CL lines separator. It could be because of this actually! I'll take a closer look. Thanks for hint.

Comment: It is indeed, due to a change related to line separator. From CLRF to LF when the file is recompiled.

Comment: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1999 LESS compiler always compile in LF, whatever the source line ending is using, that's why.