# Git flag non-modified files as modified when generated by LESS or if line separator has changed

Tags: git, less

I have an issue using git.

It basically flag files that haven't modified in two different cases:

- When the file has been regenerated by my LESS file watcher (for unknown reason), the content hasn't changed, it is exactly the same as before.
- When the lne separator has changed, because LESS use always LF for generated .css, whatever the line separator of the source file (less) is.

I've added a [screenshot](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByzbHcAxmCyvMTk1eTlhd084VUU/edit).

I don't understand why these files are flag as modified, it messes up my git because it cannot commit them. It's boring and recurrent in my projects.

Here is what I get with a `git status` command line:

```
    updated :         assets/linker/styles/common/alignment.css
    updated :         assets/linker/styles/common/badges.css
    updated :         assets/linker/styles/common/base.css
    updated :         assets/linker/styles/common/buttons.css
    updated :         assets/linker/styles/common/datatables.css
    updated :         assets/linker/styles/common/float.css
    updated :         assets/linker/styles/common/forms.css
    updated :         assets/linker/styles/common/panels.css
    updated :         assets/linker/styles/common/text.css
    updated :         assets/linker/styles/devices/layouts/devices_default.css
    updated :         assets/linker/styles/layouts/default.css
    updated :         assets/linker/styles/themes/ayolan.css
    updated :         assets/linker/styles/views/chart.css
    updated :         assets/linker/styles/views/home.css
```

Any workaround?

Comment: You should really add all generated files to your `.gitignore`, like any other build artifact (you don't put your `target` directory or binaries in the repo, if CSS isn't your source, it shouldn't be either).

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about telling git to ignore line endings?

```
git config core.autocrlf true
```

and set your .gitattributes in your project root to

```
*.css text eol=lf
```

See [gitattributes doc](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) or [dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) for more information.

Comment: `git config core.autocrlf` => true in my current settings

Comment: I have already tried that a month ago, it fixed a few problem when I downloaded files from git remote, so they would be encoded in `CLRF` in my computer, but it doesn't ignore them or help me with my current issue. Or I missed something.

Comment: The thing is that LESS compiler *always* compile files using `LF` line endings, it doesn't seem to be customizable (I've asked) and the core.autoclrf is like ignored.

Comment: Did you try *.css text eol=lf in your .gitattributes ?

Comment: I guess I have to create a `.gitattributes` file in the project root folder, didn't know that, following doc at http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Comment: I edited the answer to include your comment to make it easier for future visitors :-)